# Group By column on SQL Server and concat inner join to that grouped column

Tags: sql-server

So I have this Query that gives me this result: (dont worry about the second ID column)

[image]

Is there any way to first Group By "Nombre" but at the same time concat the "Valor" column with the "Nombre" column after it is Grouped?

EXAMPLE:

[image]

As this:
(Under column "Nombre"): Lista clasificacion : a, b, c

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/data when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As for your question, I actually have no idea what you are asking. You need to elaborate here.

Comment: We could help you with that, but unfortunate you have not provided sample data in text but in an image. Do you really expect us to type over all that data ?

Comment: you are right i forgot about the sample data :( gonna fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data it is hard to tryout, but maybe this can help you

First I create some sample data, but I have no idea if this is correct with your data

```
declare @Lista table (Id int, Nombre varchar(50))
declare @ListaDetalle table (IdLista int, Valor varchar(10))

insert into @Lista (Id, Nombre) values (1, 'Lista clasfication'), (1, 'Lista clasfication'), (1, 'Lista clasfication'), (7, 'Lista final'), (7, 'Lista final')
insert into @ListaDetalle (IdLista, Valor) values (1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (7, 'Valor 01'), (7, 'Valor 02')
```

Now we can use this query which returns what you asked in your question

```
select l.Nombre + ': ' +
       ( select string_agg(ld2.Valor, ',')
         from   @ListaDetalle ld2
         where  ld2.IdLista = l.Id
       ) as Nombre 
from   @Lista l
  inner join @ListaDetalle ld on l.Id = ld.IdLista
group by l.Id, l.Nombre
```

The result is

```
Lista clasfication: a,b,c
Lista final: Valor 01,Valor 02
```

Comment: Wow that was awesome :O and sorry for not giving the sample data gonna fix that in other posts